# Laravel importer routine slows down over time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this routine that fetches some data from a webservice and stores it in my database. This data have 20k+ items. To save them into the database, i have to retrieve some information first and then store them. So i have this foreach loop that runs 20k+ times, performing a read and a write to the database each time.

But this approach slows down over time. It takes more than an hour to finish!

I've disabled the query log (`DB::disableQueryLog()`) but i didn't notice any gain in performance.

Here's my code:

```
$data = API::getItems();

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $otherItem = OtherItem::where('something', $item['something'])->first();
    if (!is_null($otherItem)) {
        Item::create([
            ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

As a solution i decided to pre-fetch all the `OtherItem` into a collection and it solved the problem:

```
$data = API::getItems();

$otherItems = OtherItem::all();

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $otherItem = otherItems->where('something', $item['something'])->first();
    if (!is_null($otherItem)) {
        Item::create([
            ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

But i want to understand why the first approach slows down drastically over time and what is the best way to do such sort of things.

**EDIT:**

To clarify:
I know that doing 20k queries is not performant and, in this case, performance is not important (unless it takes hours instead of minutes). I will only run this routine while in development now and then. My final approach was a mix of both answers (I haven't thought in buffering the items and insert them in batches). 
Here's the code for anyone interested:

```
$data = collect(API::getPrices());
$chunks = $data->chunk(500);

$otherItems = OtherItem::all();

foreach ($chunks as $items) {
    $buffer = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $otherItem = otherItems->where('something', $item['something'])->first();
        if (!is_null($otherItem)) {
            $buffer[] = [
                ...
            ];
        }
    }
    Item::insert($buffer);
}
```

So, what is bothering me is why is painfully slow (even with all the queries). I've decided to do some benchmarking to analyse the question further. 
With the two queries approach i get the following results:

For 6000 loop:

- Max read: 11.5232 s
- Min read: 0.0044 s
- Mean read: 0.3196 s
- Max write: 0.9133 s
- Min write: 0.0007 s
- Mean write: 0.0085 s

Every 10-20 iteractions the read time goes up to over a sec for 2-3 iteractions which is weird and i have no ideia why.

Just out of curiosity, i've also benchmarked the diference between chunking and buffering the items before inserting into the DB:

- without buffering: 1 115,4 s (18 min 35 s)
- chunking and buffering: 1064.7 s (17 min 45 s)

Comment: Do you have an index on your `something` field you use in where clause?

Comment: No, i don't. I will try that.

Comment: The more items you add to your database the longer the search will take if there isn't an index on that field. But your second solution is much better anyway. 1 query vs 20k queries.

Comment: I understand that, but the `otherItems` table remains the same size (4k). I only add items to the `items` table.

Answer (score 2):

In first code snippet, you're creating 40000 queries for 20000 items. It's two queries per item - first will get the data, second will store something.

Second code snippet will create 20001 query and it's very slow solution too.

You can build an array and use `insert()` instead of using `create()` method each time you want to store some data. So this code will create just 2 queries instead of 40000 and 20001.

```
$otherItems = OtherItem::all();
$items = [];

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $otherItem = otherItems->where('something', $item['something'])->first();
    if (!is_null($model)) {
        $items[] = [.....];
    }
}

Item::insert($items);
```

Comment: If you use the bulk insert like this make sure you set the `created_at` and `updated_at` manually when you create the array if you have them in your table. I don't believe it will set those automatically with this method.

Comment: @Pitchinnate it will create nothing automatically, so yes, you should manually add `created_at`, `updated_at`, `deleted_at` fields to the array manually.

Answer (score 0):

It slows down because there's simply so many queries - each one is a round trip to the database.

Another thing you can do is try chunking the inserts with database transactions. Play around with the exact numbers but try inserting in batches of a few hundred or so.

i.e.

- start transaction
- loop over chunk, performing inserts
- commit
- repeat for next chunk until no chunks remain

Laravel's ORM provides a [chunk method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#chunking-results) for this kind of use case.